# pass javac -processorpath or gradle annotationProcessorPath via environment variable or system property

Tags: java, gradle, javac

Modern Gradle does not discover annotation processors by default. The 3rd-party low-code solution we use calls Gradle internally and to compile our java classes and we want it to discover the annotation processor in a jar with known path.

Unfortunately, `build.gradle` is generated and we can't make changes to it, but we can set environment variables and java system properties.

The generated `build.gradle` calls `JavaCompile` with some options, but it does not allow custom options.

I was hoping there's some environment variable like `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, but recognized by `javac`. Or a system property, something like `javax.annotation.processing.ProcessorPath`. Or a gradle variable like `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_compile_annotationProcessorPath`. Or hook `objectFactory.newInstance(CompileOptions.class)`

The generated task looks like this:

```
tasks.register("compile", JavaCompile) {
    source = ...
    classpath = ...
    destinationDirectory.set(...)
}
```